# cannot access a value from a different class

Tags: android, class, android-alertdialog

In my main class i've a button to call a class which shows a dialog box with an edittext. My problem is this - Main activity is not getting edittext value at the first run, if i run it for a second time, i get the old edittext value.

It seems the main activity class executes the full block of code and returns a previous value which is stored in the class, i've tried many methods including shared preference.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText comment_et,input_et;
    Spinner spinner;
    Button addbutton,reportbut;
    String input_string,date,time,comment,item;
    TextView date_tv,time_tv;
    String temp[];
    Datas datatemp;
    String savedinput;

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0);
        savedinput=  prefs.getString("KEY_SAVEDINPUT","");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spin1);
        input_et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_et);
        addbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
        reportbut = (Button)findViewById(R.id.report);

        comment_et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.comment_et);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        date_tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.date_tv);
        time_tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time_tv);

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        date = ""+mDay+"/"+mMonth+1+"/"+mYear;
        time = ""+mHour+":"+mMinute;
        date_tv.setText(date);
        time_tv.setText(time);

        int max_id = db.getDatasCount();

        for(int i = 1; i<max_id+1 ;i++)
         {          

        datatemp = db.getItemOnly(i);
        String s = datatemp._item.toString();
        list.add("   "+ s);
         }


        addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

                alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Enter Item",
                        "Please enter the spinner item",
                        true);
                System.out.println("main : " +savedinput);

            }   

        });



            reportbut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListviewActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }

            });


        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


            }
        });

        Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                 comment  = comment_et.getText().toString();

                    System.out.println("comment:"+comment);

                /**
                 * CRUD Operations
                 * */
                // Inserting Contacts
                Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
                db.addData(new Datas(item, comment, date, time));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Submitted Successfully",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Reading all contacts
                Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
                List<Datas> datas = db.getAllDatas();       

                for (Datas d : datas) {
                    String log = "Id: "+d.getID()+" ,Item: " + d.getItem() + " ,Comment: " + d.getComment() + " ,Date: " + d.getDate() + ",Comment: " + d.getTime();
                        // Writing Contacts to log
                Log.d("Item: ", log);
                }
            }
        });
}

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**AlertDialogManager.java**

```
public class AlertDialogManager {
    /**
     * Function to display simple Alert Dialog
     * @param context - application context
     * @param title - alert dialog title
     * @param message - alert message
     * @param status - success/failure (used to set icon)
     *               - pass null if you don't want icon
     * */
    String savedinput;
    public void showAlertDialog(final Context context, String title, String message,
            Boolean status) 
    {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        //setting input
         final EditText input = new EditText(context);
         alertDialog.setView(input);

         // saving input to a string
         savedinput = input.getText().toString();
         System.out.println(savedinput);

        if(status != null)
            // Setting alert dialog icon
            alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                savedinput = input.getText().toString();

                SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor =prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("KEY_SAVEDINPUT", savedinput);
                editor.commit();                
                System.out.println("from class "+savedinput);
            }
        });



        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();

    }

    String getItem()
    {
        return savedinput;
    }
}
```

and here is my logcat, just for further clarification

```
02-01 13:48:43.372: I/System.out(897): main : firstexecute
02-01 13:48:46.942: W/KeyCharacterMap(897): No keyboard for id 0
02-01 13:48:46.942: W/KeyCharacterMap(897): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-01 13:48:49.532: I/System.out(897): from class secondexecute
```

Comment: where u are not getting value ?

Comment: i am not getting the values in the main activity from the class, the class itself is getting values to a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several issues here.

1. You shouldn't read `savedValue` in `onCreate`, you should do it only when you actually use it. See @ρяσѕρєяK answer.
2. `alert.showAlertDialog` is non blocking. So after dialog is shown line `System.out.println("main : " + savedInput);` is executed. It **doesn't wait** for your input. So you should call some other action beside saving to shared preferences on dialog's ok buttonn. This action should invoke logic that should happen after user entered some text in the dialog.

**Update**

```
public void showAlertDialog(final Context context, String title, String message,
                            Boolean status, final Spinner spinner) 
{
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);

    //setting input
     final EditText input = new EditText(context);
     alertDialog.setView(input);

     // saving input to a string
     savedinput = input.getText().toString();
     System.out.println(savedinput);

    if(status != null)
        // Setting alert dialog icon
        alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            savedinput = input.getText().toString();
            // do whatever you want with spinner and savedInput here.
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
 }
```

onClick to show dialog:

```
alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Enter Item",
     "Please enter the spinner item",
     true, (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin1));
```

**Update 2**
Apparently you need to add new item to your spinner adapter. For this you can create list of all items and pass this list along with adapter to dialog. When user enters string and press OK button `onClick` method adds this string to the list and call `notifyDataSetChanged` to update UI:

Add this in `MainActivity`:

```
List<String> spinnerItems;
```

In `onCreate`:

```
spinnerItems = new ArrayList<String>();
adapter = enw ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 0, spinnerItems);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Pass `spinnerItems` and `adapter` to `showAlertDialog`:

```
alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Enter Item",
     "Please enter the spinner item",
     true, spinnerItems, adapter);
```

And finally add text to list and notify adapter:

```
alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        savedinput = input.getText().toString();
        spinnerItems.add(savedInput);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: hi, but we can get latest value from SharedPreferences in onResume of Activity

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK yes, it's an option. My point was that it shouldn't be invoked right after dialog is shown.

Comment: @agen451 when you exactly need `savedInput`? What do use it for?

Comment: i need savedInput to save it to my spinner

Comment: @agen451 pass spinner to `showAlertDialog` so you set text to the spinner in dialog's `onClick`.

Comment: how do i pass spinner to that method

Comment: it shows an error like - The method showAlertDialog(Context, String, String, Boolean, Spinner) in the type AlertDialogManager is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity, String, String, boolean)

Comment: @agen451 I've posted also modified version of `showAlertDialog`. Check it.

Comment: @agen451 I don't know. I posted modified version of `showAlertDialog` that includes Spinner as last argument. You can manually fix it. The main idea is that you can access spinner fomr `onClick` in dialog.

Comment: there is another problem we should use array adapter for the purpose of setting spinner items... but in alertdialogmanager class shows an error 'its undefined for alert dilog builder'

Comment: @agen451 you should cleaner explain what you want to achieve. What is spinner? You want to add new item to spinner from dialog?

Comment: thank you very much, you spent more time with my code finally you did it thank you for everything this help is awesome to me cause am a biginer

Answer (score 1):

you will need get latest value on Button click instead of onCreate to get latest value from SharedPreferences as :

```
addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
           AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

           alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Enter Item",
                        "Please enter the spinner item",
                        true);
           savedinput=  prefs.getString("KEY_SAVEDINPUT",""); //<<< get value here
           System.out.println("main : " +savedinput);

       }   

   });
```

or you will try to get value from onResume of Activity

Comment: this doesn't help me, should i try thread concepts, just to solve this issue?

Comment: @agen451 : you can do one more trick declare savedinput in AlertDialogManager as public static String savedinput  then try to get value and check u are getting latest from it or not

Answer (score 0):

This

```
savedinput = input.getText().toString();
```

is evaluated when it is run. Not when you call `getItem()`. The value you'll get is what it was, in this case, before the alert was displayed.

same logic goes for

```
savedinput=  prefs.getString("KEY_SAVEDINPUT","");
```

Comment: i'm happy that you got my question right. Is there any options to get value from the class at the same time?